# Runing in local model the wordcount lines=sc.textFile('../spark_test.txt') lines.count()

Tags: pyspark

I run pyspark in the local model to learn the wordcount case. I write a spark_test.txt in current file, and run pyspark command , `lines = sc.textFile('../spark_test.txt') lines.count()`, it throws out a bug:

> Input path does not exist: file:/Users/lisl/myproject/spark_test.txt

** I tried:**

```
sc.textFile('spark_test.txt')

lines = sc.textFile('../spark_test.txt')
lines.count()
```

i expect the outpub be the number of lines of the file , but the actual output is :

```
file "/Users/lisl/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/Users/lisl/myproject/learn_test/spark_test.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some lines of code are missing. Please try the code below and make sure that the path to your file exist and you have given read access for all to it (`chmod a+r yourFile`)

```
text_file = sc.textFile("path/to/your/input/file")
wordCounts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
         .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
         .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
wordCounts.saveAsTextFile("path/to/your/output/file")
```